# azure monitor alerts creation best usecase

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cloud-shell, azure-alerts

what is the best way to automate the azuremonitor logsearch based and metric based alerts in more transparent way, where we can easily update the threshold values. it shoul be capable to automate using azure pipelines

Comment: Create the alert using ARM templates and put the threshold in variables? See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric-create-templates)

Comment: that wont help in my scenarios where i want to reuse the same json with multiple inputs , where i am using azure pipeline. Alos for different kind of laerts same json file cant be used i guess: for example there are multiple aggrgationvalues type are there for logasearch based alerts, example: :"cout", "Total" etc.. for ll these categoeies we have different options available. the same for metric based type as well.